# Unable to call sub with if

Tags: vb.net, module, call, subroutine

I am trying to call validation with if but the same not working and other line is continue executing, please help.

```
Private Sub BtnCreateInvioce_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCreateInvioce_Save.Click
    If txtvalidation() = True Then

        PrintPreviewModule.Document = PrintModule

        add_items()
        PrintPreviewModule.ShowDialog()
        estimateclear()
        janAutoNumberUpdate("invoiceno")
        frmestimate_Load(sender, e)
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could the problem be in the `txtvalidation` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `txtvalidation()` function with something like this:

```
Public Function txtvalidation() as boolean
    return True
End Function
```

then, click on the *BtnCreateInvioce_Save* button. If works in this way, the problem is the `txtvalidation()` function that not produce the expected value.
Post this function code so we can understand what the problem is.

A tip: it is not necessary to write

```
If txtvalidation() = True Then 
...
```

You can simply write

```
If txtvalidation() Then 
...
```